# Display menu list on Double Tap gesture - Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I'm new to IOS and I'm trying to display list of buttons on double tap of UIView. I have the below code to capture the double tap gesture:

```
let menuTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showMenuPanel(_:)))
        menuTap.minimumPressDuration = 0.0
        menuTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        menuTap.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(menuTap)


func showMenuPanel(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        print("TESTPANEL")

    }
```

[image]

I need to design a panel to show a list of buttons such as start, stop and pause. Can anybody guide me on how to design a panel on the tapped position?

Comment: It's just a UIView object with a bunch of UIButton objects placed over the same number of UIView objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` for that not the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. Set `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `numberOfTapsRequired` to `2`.

```
let menuTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showMenuPanel(_:)))
menuTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

//No need to set isUserInteractionEnabled to true because by default it is true for `UIView`
//self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true 
self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(menuTap)
```

Add action method of tapGesture like this.

```
func showMenuPanel(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("TESTPANEL")
    let point = recognizer.location(in: self.view)
    //Get your view from nib
    let view = CustomView()
    //set its origin to this point
    view.frame.origin = point
    //add your view in self.view
    self.view.addSubview(view)
}
```

Comment: @US-1234 Add screen shot of your requirement that will give us idea what you want.

Comment: added screen design

Comment: @US-1234 At location of double tap you want to show this view?

Comment: @US-1234 Welcome mate :)